# ionic 5 routing error: Cannot find any routes

Tags: angular, master-detail, ionic5

New Ionic 5 project.  I am trying to add pages to the "tabs" folder in order to keep the tab bar at the bottom.  I have added to pages via the CLI.  The pages and routes as usual are added two the *app-routing.module.ts* and everything works fine.  I created a button on *tab1.page.ts* and can navigate to both new pages.

One page basic function on *tab1.page.ts* is:

```
goToBooth(){
    console.log("clicked goToBooth");
    this.navCtrl.navigateForward('booth-product-list');
  }
```

Here are the *app-routing.module.ts* routes in question:

```
{
        path: 'booth-product-list',
        loadChildren: () => import('../booth-product-list/booth-product-list.module').then( m => m.BoothProductListPageModule)
      },
      {
        path: 'booth-detail-list',
        loadChildren: () => import('../booth-detail-list/booth-detail-list.module').then( m => m.BoothDetailListPageModule)
      }
```

But the new pages don't have the tab bar at the bottom as the url has changed.  So I move the routes from *app-routing.module.ts* to *tabs-routing.module.ts*.  I get the following error in the console:

**ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'booth-product-list'**

I am sure I am over looking something small but I just can not figure it out.  Please help a nube if you can.

Comment: hello @detourOfReason, if your want to route new page with tabs then you have to give navigation routing like

    **this.navCtrl.navigateForward('tabs/booth-product-list');**

Comment: @AniruddhThakor Thank you so much!  This solved my issue.  if you add this as the answer I will mark it as the accepted answer.  Thanks.

Comment: Yes sure, happy to help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if your want to route new page with tabs then you have to give navigation routing like

```
this.navCtrl.navigateForward('tabs/booth-product-list');
```